# How can I prevent other characters from being inputted on an input except numbers using Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, input

I am using Vue.JS (Bootstrap-Vue) to build a form, my input has the following code:

```
<b-form-input
            v-mask="'####'"
            number
            type="number"
            no-wheel
            pattern="[0-9]"
            step="1"
            :class="{ 'hasError': $v.form.dobYear.$error }"
            v-model.number="$v.form.dobYear.$model"
            class="form-input"
            name="year"
            id="year"
            maxlength="4"
            min="1900"
            max="2020"
            @keydown="filterKey"
          ></b-form-input>
```

When a user presses down I want to prevent more than **4 characters** to be entered, this works, but when testing, I can see period and dashes and other similar characters can also be added into the input and ignores the maximum of **4 characters**. How can I update the following code to ensure nothing but numbers can be added to my input on mobile. I'm trying to detect if any of those unwanted keys are pressed then prevent the default action. (I've tested on Android Chrome)

```
filterKey(e) {
      const value = e.target.value;
      const key = e.key;
      console.log(value, this.amount);
      if (String(value).length === 4) {
        //check if a number is pressed after 4 have been entered
        if (!isNaN(Number(key))) {
          e.preventDefault();
          return;
        } else if (key == 190 || key == 189 || key == 107 || key == 69) {
          e.preventDefault();
          return;
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The following snippet will not allow anything to be entered into the input element if the length of the input's value is already 4, or if a non-numeric character is typed (but will allow 'Backspace' and 'Delete' keys):

**EDIT : Implemented Hiws' suggestion to let the user type in numbers even if the length is 4, if some text is selected in the input element**

```
function filterKey(e) {
    let previousValue = e.target.value;
    let key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
    if (key != 8 && key != 46) { // Ignore backspace and delete
        if (
            // preventDefault if length of input is 4 and no text is selected in the input
            ( String(e.target.value).length >= 4 && e.target.selectionStart === e.target.selectionEnd ) ||
            // preventDefault if entered a space or non-number
            !e.key.trim() || isNaN(e.key)
            ) {
            // Prevent input if input length crosses 4,
            // or if input is not a number
            e.preventDefault();
            // Include below line only if you have no other event listeners on the element, or its parents
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            return;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It could be worth adding a check to whether the text in the input is selected or not. Since a user could select some text to replace it. But with this code if there's already 4 characters nothing would happen.

Comment: It makes perfect sense, but I don't understand why this still won't work when testing on Android mobile? It still allows me to enter the other characters on the numerical keyboard.

Comment: @ImranR Did a bit of research and it appears that `.preventDefault()` doesn't stop the value from being entered on android chrome. You might need to figure out a different solution

Comment: @Hiws I see, that would explain why I'm going round in circles :) Thanks for sharing!

Comment: @ImranR Could you try calling e.stopImmediatePropagation() too after e.preventDefault() ? This would prevent other handlers and parent handlers from executing (Did a little research, and some people reported this solution to have worked for them)

Comment: I tried with your updated code @HarshitVadodaria, however, it still didn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

You block keys other than numbers only if number value already equals to `4`. Try changing your blocking logic to:

```
if (String(value).length > 4 || !isNaN(Number(key)) || unwanted keyCodes) {
   e.preventDefault();
   return;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to test against the value of the input field and avoid messing with keyCodes.

```js
if ( !/^[0-9]{0,4}$/.test(String(value)) ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this still allows me to enter the other unwanted characters.

Comment: Try adding some prints to debug if it enters the if